# Create slice of unknown type?

Tags: go, couchbase

I'm trying to fetch multiple values using this function (from [go-couchbase](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase/blob/master/client.go#L544)).

```
func (b *Bucket) Gets(k string, rv interface{}, caso *uint64) error {
    data, _, cas, err := b.GetsRaw(k)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if caso != nil {
        *caso = cas
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, rv)
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to create a slice of rv, since I don't know its type in my function, and I have no idea how big it will be so I can't really access the `rv` slice through indexes, right?

I want to be as general as possible, so creating a function per `rv` struct isn't really optimal and the [GetBulk](https://godoc.org/github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase#Bucket.GetBulk) function only returns a `[]byte`.

Is it even possible to do what I want in go?

Comment: Are you saying that a slice is passed into this function via the `rv` argument?

Comment: no, i'm trying to build a function around the `Gets` function, so I need a "slice of rv's" so I can send in one rv at a time, by reference.

Comment: Why don't you create a slice of interface{}?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inspect the type information using the `reflect` package.  If we have a function that has an argument `rv interface{}` where we expect a pointer to a slice to be passed in, we can create a `reflect.Value` that refers to that slice:

```
slice := reflect.ValueOf(rv).Elem()
```

We can reinitialise the slice as follows:

```
slice.Set(reflect.MakeSlice(slice.Type(), length, capacity))
```

We can determine the element type of this slice with:

```
elemType := slice.Type().Elem()
```

And then create another `reflect.Value` that represents a pointer to a newly allocated instance of that type:

```
v := reflect.New(elemType)
```

Now `v.Interface()` would be appropriate to pass to a function like `json.Unmarshal`.  Once it has been filled, it can be appended to the slice:

```
slice.Set(reflect.Append(slice, v.Elem()))
```

For a full example that decodes a slice of JSON documents into an arbitrary slice type, see http://play.golang.org/p/G-SHQO2MAT

Answer (score 2):

Considering [`go-couchbase#Bucket.Gets`](https://godoc.org/github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase#Bucket.Gets) takes an interface, you need to put your objects into a []interface, as describe in wiki page "[InterfaceSlice](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/InterfaceSlice)"

```
var dataSlice []int = foo()
var interfaceSlice []interface{} = make([]interface{}, len(dataSlice))
for i, d := range dataSlice {
    interfaceSlice[i] = d
}
```

That means you already have a slice of "something", and know its size.

Or, since you want to "build a function around the `Gets` function", you could have the same signature, and use a simple `interface{}` instead of `[]interface`.